# How do I fix this debugger detected error that occurs while launching the game client?

Tags: blade-and-soul

Whenever I try to launch the game, this error pops up and the game won't start. I have added the Blade and Soul exe file to my exceptions list on my antivirus (a possible solution I found online), but it doesn't seem to have changed anything. Is there a different exe file I need to add to my exceptions list, or is there something else I can do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I hate "protection" like that.

Comment: Any other background processes running that it could potentially find suspect?

Comment: @pushasha none that I can think would be found suspect. I have my standard windows 10 processes, a few things from my antivirus, a few browsers, some intel and amd things, and that is mostly it

Comment: @Dragonrage You said you already looked at some solutions online, but just to double check -- have you made sure that Windows has all its updates installed, and that your drivers (sound/video) are up-to-date? The [Microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812759) for this error mentions those as a potential cause.

Comment: @pushasha yes, I just updated my drivers and all windows updates are up-to-date

Comment: @Dragonrage Okay, one more sanity check: have you tried running after a clean boot (procedure described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/331796))?

Comment: @pushasha I haven't run a clean boot. I'll try that when I get a chance. Tad busy ATM, but will let you know the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix that works for me. It appears that GameGaurd has a problem with an antivirus program scanning it, so what I did was add the folder for the game as an exception. This allowed me to launch the game without the error message, and I was able to play normally.